# Getting started with reportlab on raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, reportlab

I'm having trouble getting started with reportlab on a raspberry pi. My pi claims that reportlab-3.5.59 is successfully installed. However the suggested startup test program below fails at line 1 with ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'reportlab'

### Any ideas?

from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
def hello(c):
c.drawstring(100,100,"Hello pdf world")
c = canvas.Canvas("hello.pdf")
hello(c)
c.showPage()
c.save()

Comment: Hi Robert, I would suggest you rephrase your question describing your issue in the first line like "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'reportlab' on raspberry pi"

Answer (score 0):

D'oh! I've found the answer. I needed to install with pip3 rather than pip.